# Flurry log event updation is quite late as compared its session in iPhone SDK

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, flurry

I integrated flurry with my iPhone app, Its working fine but its log event section update quite late as compared its session updating. It show me 3 days previous log event history but in session its showing me today session history also. I reched my code which was fine. I don't know why this happen. Kindly help me on this if some one already face this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It initially takes sometime to update custom events. If it is actually taking a lot of time regularly. You must reach out to support@flurry.com . They would respond back in 24hours and provide support.